# Modeing conjunction logic in graph

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, titan

I am trying to model complex implications between nodes in graph. For example, it is easy to implement "If A then B" when A and B are simple nodes and have an edge of 'Implies'.

But how can I model a conditional logic? 
ie - "If (A and B) or (C and D) then E"?

Thanks

Comment: Could you give a more detailed example? Perhaps what you have so far using Cypher? Perhaps the [`OPTIONAL MATCH`](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-optional-match.html) clause is what you are looking for.

Comment: Let's say I have a database of events (interest rate will rise, crude oil price will decline) and I want to model implications between them (if interest rate will rise then crude oil price will decline). In this example, I can have 2 entities with an 'implication' edge between them.

Now, let's say I have a 3rd event - "GDP will rise" and I want to model - "If interest rates will rise (A) AND crude oil price will decline (B)  then GDP will rise (C).

Answer (score 0):

How about modelling the logical operators as nodes? You would have a node with the label `:And`, with two (or more) incoming `:CONDITION` relationships and one outgoing `:IMPLIES` relationship. You could chain these by having outgoing `:CONDITION` relationships into other operators `:Or`, `:Xor`, `:Not`, etc.

To query for events that could happen as an effect of a certain event, you could then use this form:

```
MATCH (cause:Event {id: 'A'})-[:CONDITION|IMPLIES*]->(effect:Event)
RETURN effect.id AS effectsOfA
```